# Jetty - how to get time spent in the accept queue?

Tags: java, jetty

our application is seeing some latency issues when clients are connecting to our Jetty server.  We can see the time spent in the dispatcher thread is very low (10ms), but how can I find the time the request was on the accept queue before being processed?

We are currently using Jetty 6.1.24 on a Linux OS, with 20 acceptor (possibly too high), 20 dispatcher threads and a queue size of 512.  The preferable solution would be log4j settings if Jetty has any debug logging in this area, but we could also implement specific listeners to find this timing if need be.

Comment: I'll just chime in that the recommended number of acceptor threads is the number of CPUs.  Anything more then that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @drakkanraz,  did you find any solution ?

Comment: hi, did you find a solution (after 10yr)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a JMX connection via JConsole? (just type jconsole into your shell; the app is part of the jdk)

Maybe (and probably) the server presents some JMX interfaces for retrieving such information...

Comment: JMX cannot possibly present an interface for such information, as it isn't available to Java.

Comment: Indeed, this information isn't available in JMX. Additionally I was looking for something real-time that we can translate to a log message.